# Onclick js selected parent but i want only children

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a problem with my onlick, when i click, parent div is selected too:

my log when i click on  my div id 90968

```
90968 img.js:19:13
bodybloc img.js:19:13
bloc img.js:19:13
<empty string>
```

with this code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'div', function () {
console.log(this.id);
```

})

i want only 90968, and not other div parent but how ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can assign an ID to the child element only and not the parent.

And the onclick becomes

```
$('#childID').on('click', 'div', function () {
   console.log(this.id);
})
```

Comment: I can't, because I generate lots of divs, and then I would like to click on the divs and find their id for personalized ones